# How can I change the title in Joomla?

Tags: joomla

Please someone to help ! How can I change the title in Joomla? I tried all the options (mainmenu - Page Display Options - Show Page Heading), and none of it did not help me.

http://nedim.byethost7.com/

Pls help !

Answer (score 1):

Try this

If you are tring with page title you can use as follows

```
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $document->setTitle('Title of Page');
```

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the browser title ( tag), this is usually set in the Joomla global configuration and/or in the template options.

Comment: I've changed all the information in the template in the global configuration, nothing happened ...

Comment: Looks like you figured it out now? Maybe JoomFish issue?